# How can i calculate the time of ad posting using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hello Everyone,
               Can somebody tell me how can i count a time of a post that is online. Means i have a site of adposting, i want to count how can i calculate the online time of ad is posted, like

2 Days gone ad is online
3 Days gone ad is online

Here is an example
http://www.buyandsell.ie/motors/classic-cars/kerry/head-gasket-sealer-3

You can see in this site, online time is 9 days since ad is posting.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have posted an ad on Christmass. The date is saved in mysql as `2012-12-25`. Now you want to display how many days its has been posted. Use [DateTime](http://php.net/DateTime), [DateInterval](http://php.net/DateInterval) classes like this.

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", "2012-12-25");
$interval = $d->diff(new DateTime());
echo $interval->format("%a days"); // echos '6 days'
```

See more the [code in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dFzrIz)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

//time() will give current time and
//$time will have the time from database when the post was posted on your site.
$time_difference = time() - $time ;

//calculate the difference and show accordingly.
$seconds = $time_difference ;
$minutes = round($time_difference / 60 );
$hours = round($time_difference / 3600 );
$days = round($time_difference / 86400 );
$weeks = round($time_difference / 604800 );
$months = round($time_difference / 2419200 );
$years = round($time_difference / 29030400 );
if($seconds <= 60)
{
    echo "<font id='big'>a few seconds ago</font>";
}
//Minutes
else if($minutes <=60)
{
    if ($minutes==1) {
        echo "1 minute ago";
    }
    else {
        echo $minutes." minutes ago";
    }
}
else if($hours <=24) {
    if ($hours==1) {
        echo "1 hour ago";
    }
    else {
        echo $hours." hours ago";
    }
}
else if($days <= 7)
{
    if ($days==1) {
        echo "Yesterday";
    }
    else {
        echo $days." days ago";
    }
}
else if($weeks <= 4)
{
    if ($weeks==1) {
        echo "1 week ago";
    }
    else {
        echo $weeks." weeks ago";
    }
}
else if($months <=12)
{
    if ($months==1) {
        echo "1 month ago";
    }
    else {
        echo $months." months ago";
    }
}
else
{
    if ($years==1) {
        echo "1 year ago";
    }
    else {
        echo $years." years ago";
   }
}
?>
```